# Open SSL and PHP with Server to Server API

Tags: php, openssl

I am working with the below simple example using open ssl to encrypt and decrypt a signature and data in a message.  I'm trying to get an understanding of how the public and private key and signature works with data communication between two websites.

What I'd like to do is send data to an api on another website via curl and in the API be able verify the signature and unpack the data if openssl_verify is true.

I am getting an error in the last command of the API section indicating the $data is not defined.

I have three questions:

1. How could I fix this error?
2. In the API portion, I am a little confused on the best practice to confirm the signature and unpack the data.  Is there a better way to do this then what I am trying to do?
3. Could the API verify process be done easier with oauth2 (there is no user input when API)?

The below code is for website 1 after user submits a web form it captures the name from the form and uses open ssl to encrypt the name and also creates a signature.

```
<?php
        
        //Private key here for testing only, realize this has be be in highly secure location.
        $private_key = <<<EOD
        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
        MIIBOgIBAAJBANDiE2+Xi/WnO+s120NiiJhNyIButVu6zxqlVzz0wy2j4kQVUC4Z
        RZD80IY+4wIiX2YxKBZKGnd2TtPkcJ/ljkUCAwEAAQJAL151ZeMKHEU2c1qdRKS9
        sTxCcc2pVwoAGVzRccNX16tfmCf8FjxuM3WmLdsPxYoHrwb1LFNxiNk1MXrxjH3R
        6QIhAPB7edmcjH4bhMaJBztcbNE1VRCEi/bisAwiPPMq9/2nAiEA3lyc5+f6DEIJ
        h1y6BWkdVULDSM+jpi1XiV/DevxuijMCIQCAEPGqHsF+4v7Jj+3HAgh9PU6otj2n
        Y79nJtCYmvhoHwIgNDePaS4inApN7omp7WdXyhPZhBmulnGDYvEoGJN66d0CIHra
        I2SvDkQ5CmrzkW5qPaE2oO7BSqAhRZxiYpZFb5CI
        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
        EOD;
        
        $public_key = <<<EOD
        -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
        MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBANDiE2+Xi/WnO+s120NiiJhNyIButVu6
        zxqlVzz0wy2j4kQVUC4ZRZD80IY+4wIiX2YxKBZKGnd2TtPkcJ/ljkUCAwEAAQ==
        -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
        EOD;
        
        if (isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name']!="") {
        
            $binary_signature = "";
            $data = $_POST['name'];
            echo $data;
        
            openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $public_key, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
        
            $data = base64_encode($encrypted);
        
            openssl_sign($data, $binary_signature, $private_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
        
            $binary_signature=base64_url_encode($binary_signature);
            $url = "http://localhost/api/api.php?binary_signature=".$binary_signature;
            
            $client = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            $response = curl_exec($client);
            $result = json_decode($response);
        
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr><td>Name:</td><td>$result->data</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Amount:</td><td>$result->amount</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Response Code:</td><td>$result->response_code</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Response Desc:</td><td>$result->response_desc</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
        
        }
        
        function base64_url_encode($input) {
            return strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/=', '-_,');
        }
        
?>
```

This is website 2 where the api lives.  The goal is to verify the signature and unpack the message.  I am getting an error at $ok = because it can not find $data.

```
     <?php
    
     //Private key here for testing only, realize this has be be in highly secure location.
    $private_key = <<<EOD
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
    MIIBOgIBAAJBANDiE2+Xi/WnO+s120NiiJhNyIButVu6zxqlVzz0wy2j4kQVUC4Z
    RZD80IY+4wIiX2YxKBZKGnd2TtPkcJ/ljkUCAwEAAQJAL151ZeMKHEU2c1qdRKS9
    sTxCcc2pVwoAGVzRccNX16tfmCf8FjxuM3WmLdsPxYoHrwb1LFNxiNk1MXrxjH3R
    6QIhAPB7edmcjH4bhMaJBztcbNE1VRCEi/bisAwiPPMq9/2nAiEA3lyc5+f6DEIJ
    h1y6BWkdVULDSM+jpi1XiV/DevxuijMCIQCAEPGqHsF+4v7Jj+3HAgh9PU6otj2n
    Y79nJtCYmvhoHwIgNDePaS4inApN7omp7WdXyhPZhBmulnGDYvEoGJN66d0CIHra
    I2SvDkQ5CmrzkW5qPaE2oO7BSqAhRZxiYpZFb5CI
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    EOD;
    
    $public_key = <<<EOD
    -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBANDiE2+Xi/WnO+s120NiiJhNyIButVu6
    zxqlVzz0wy2j4kQVUC4ZRZD80IY+4wIiX2YxKBZKGnd2TtPkcJ/ljkUCAwEAAQ==
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    EOD;

   if (isset($_GET['binary_signature']) && $_GET['binary_signature']!="") {
        
        $signature=$_GET['binary_signature'];
                
        $signature=base64_decode($signature);
        
        
        // Check signature
        $ok = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $public_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

     // more code would go here to test if verify is ok and then unpack the message.

    ?>
```

Comment: Where is $data in the 2nd file? it is not defined .. why should it be known? aren't you missing a line: $data = $_GET['encrypted_data'];  or something like it????  where does $data come from? you need to pass it and define it.

Comment: @Shlomtzion  that makes sense to me on the variable $data in the API.   In the first site I thought `openssl_sign($data, $binary_signature, $private_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);` packages the data within $binary_signature variable.   Is that the case and if so how can I access the data in $binary_signature within the API?

Comment: $url = "http://localhost/api/api.php?binary_signature=".$binary_signature;
 Here you sent the $_GET['binary_signature'] via the ?binary_signature=".$binary_signature; so add after it: ."&data=".$data; so you'' have: $url = "http://localhost/api/api.php?binary_signature=".$binary_signature."&data=".$data;  and now you'll be able to use $_GET['data'] in the api file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the $data variable in the url as well from the first file to the api.php file - change the $url to:

```
$url = "http://localhost/api/api.php?binary_signature=".$binary_signature."&data=".$data;
```

Do this in the first file and you will be able to do :
`$data = $_GET['data'];` in the api.php file place this after the `$signature=base64_decode($signature);` and before the :

```
// Check signature
    $ok = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $public_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
```

I.E. - (api.php) - showing relevant area:

```
if (isset($_GET['binary_signature']) && $_GET['binary_signature']!="") {
    
    $signature=$_GET['binary_signature'];
            
    $signature=base64_decode($signature);
    
    $data = $_GET['data'];
    
    // Check signature
    $ok = openssl_verify($data, $signature, $public_key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);

 // more code would go here to test if verify is ok and then unpack the message.

?>
```